# Deleted Users Confusion/Worry

Tags: macos, finder, imac, user-account, dmg

I found a 'Deleted Users' folder, which apeard on the side bar of the finder some how, which I've never seen before. I'm confused how they got here and why I never saw them before.

It has two .dmg and one is 'aspnet.dmg' I don't know what that even is?

The other seems to be my older personal user account, lets just say its called 'M.dmg' which I again don't know how it got there. I did transfer my old computer on to this but i don't remember deleting it on my mac or anything about it ending up in this Deleted Users folder.

I'm just worried what these things are and how they got there. They both apparently have 1gb of data but I cant find anything inside them other than a few older personal files in the 'M.dmg'.

Basically I'm just worried what these are exactly. They both have about 1gb of data but I cant see anything other than a few things in the old user .dmg and I have no idea what aspnet.dmg even is.

***Edit**:* I'm mostly confused and worried how they got there, is there anything I should be worried about or is it just me being stupid and not knowing? Also they both say they're 1gb each even though they seem to be empty, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The Deleted Users folder contains DMGs of users that you've deleted. When deleting a user in System Preferences → Users & Groups, you are given the option of saving that user's home folder as a DMG in a Deleted Users folder:

[image]

> - Save the home folder in a disk image
>     <sup>The disk image is saved in the Deleted Users folder (in the Users folder).</sup>

Selecting the *Save the home folder in a disk image* option will cause the home folder of the deleted account to be saved in a disk image

[image]

If there's nothing in the account that you want any more, you can safely delete the disk image from the Deleted Users folder, or even the entire Deleted Users folder itself.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1hEDZT4

Comment: @Buscar웃 Could you elaborate?

Comment: What is aspnet :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 If you're attempting to be rhetorical I don't understand…

Comment: Never mind, the joke is not fresh anymore. Just trying to be funny in answering the question about what is aspnet.

Comment: @grgarside Hey thank you this was helpful! My main worry now is i don't remember deleting them or ever seeing that screen you showed. I edited my question slightly if you can offer any more help it would be appreciated!